# Apollo Client - using cached results from object list in response to query for single object

Tags: javascript, caching, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Is it possible to configure the Apollo Client to fetch a single cached Item from a query that returns a list of Items, in order to prefetch data when querying for a single Item?

Schema:

```
type Item {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  items: [Item!]!
  itemById(id: ID!): Item!
}
```

Query1:

```
query HomepageList {
  items {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Query2:

```
query ItemDetail($id: ID!) {
  itemById(id: $id) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Given that the individual Item's data will already be in the cache, it should be possible to use the already cached data whilst still executing a fetch incase any data has changed.

However, the query does not utilise the cached data (by default at least), and it seems that we need to somehow tell Apollo that we know the Item is already in the cache.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This functionality exists, but it's hard to find if you don't know what you're looking for. In Apollo Client v2 you're looking for cache redirect functionality, in Apollo Client v3 this is replaced by type policies / field read policies ([v3 docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#cache-redirects-using-field-policy-read-functions)).

Apollo doesn't 'know' your GraphQL schema and that makes it easy to set up and work with in day-to-day usage. However, this implies that given some query (e.g. `getBooks`) it doesn't know what the result type is going to be *upfront*. It does know it afterwards, as long as the __typename's are enabled. This is the default behaviour and is needed for normalized caching.

Let's assume you have a `getBooks` query that fetches a list of `Book`s. If you inspect the cache after this request is finished using Apollo devtools, you should find the books in the cache using the `Book:123` key in which `Book` is the typename and `123` is the id. If it exists (and is queried!) the `id` field is used as identifier for the cache. If your id field has another name, you can use the typePolicies of the cache to inform Apollo InMemoryCache about this field.

If you've set this up and you run a `getBook` query afterwards, using some id as input, you will **not** get any cached data. The reason is as described before: Apollo doesn't know upfront which type this query is going to return.

So in Apollo v2 you would use a cacheRedirect to 'redirect' Apollo to the right cache:

```
  cacheRedirects: {
    Query: {
      getBook(_, args, { getCacheKey }) {
        return getCacheKey({
          __typename: 'Book',
          id: args.id,
        });
      }
    },
  },
```

(`args.id` should be replaced by another identifier if you have specified another key in the typePolicy)

When using Apollo v3, you need a typepolicy / field read policy:

```
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        getBook(_, { args, toReference }) {
          return toReference({
            __typename: 'Book',
            id: args.id,
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Excellent answer @Bram, this worked and helped me understand what was going on.